# cloudwatch event in aws lambda function not work in my aws educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-events

while using cloud watch event in aws lambda function in my aws educate starter account 
i get this error

```
User: arn:aws:sts::****:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/*** is not authorized to perform: events:PutRule on resource: arn:aws:event*****:rule/onemin with an explicit deny (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: *)
```

I see lot of solution related with this like adding iam permission role and so on
but none of this work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Educate account is **very limited**. You have **explicit deny**, which means that AWS Educate admins explicitly denied that action.

While working with AWS Educate you will be encountering very often such messages.

The only thing you could try is to contact their support, hoping they would relax the restrictions for you. Alternatively, you can get regular AWS account where you are the admin, and get AWS Educate credits for your use.

General list of their restrictions is [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf). Important to note is that:

> All services may have **additional restrictions not listed** below [in the link provided].